# Glassdoor scraping using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape Glassdoor using the code given here
https://github.com/PlayingNumbers/ds_salary_proj/blob/master/glassdoor_scraper.py
While executing the code, there are no errors and the website opens, but then nothing happens. I think they have changed the tags on the website. I've tried changing the tags but it's still working.
Here's the code snippet:

```
def get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, path, slp_time):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword="' + keyword + '"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'
    driver.get(url)
    jobs = []

    while len(jobs) < num_jobs:  
        time.sleep(slp_time)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass

        time.sleep(.1)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="Close"]').click() 
            print(' x out worked')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('x out failed')
            pass
```

You can find the whole code in the link given above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `keyword` ?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_nam("selected").click(), I think you are missing the e in name

Comment: @JeremyKahan my bad that happened while copying the code here. It's not working with the right spelling too

Comment: @cruisepandey keyword is the name of the position that is to be searched for. In my code that is 'data scientist'

Comment: What is the value of `num_jobs` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey it is 5

Comment: there is no class with `selected` . Can you tell me what exactly you wanna do once URL is launched with that URL.

Comment: @cruisepandey once the URL is launched it is supposed to bypass the sign-in prompt and scrape the information about all the jobs listed under a given keyword

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the URL generated by the

```
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword="' + keyword + '"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'
```

And verify it manually if results are displayed in the page